# Check if a property exists on global or window object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to convert this JavaScript code to TypeScript:

```js
if (!window.INITIALIZED) {
  init();
  window.INITIALIZED = true;
}
runCode();
```

The `window` object is typed in TypeScript, and the compiler will throw an error saying that the property `INITIALIZED` does not exist on type `'Window & typeof globalThis'`.

How can I correctly fix this without disabling TypeScript features or ignoring the type checking for those lines?

Comment: Since `window` is global, you can just write `if(!INITIALIZED){...` and `INITIALIAZED = true` and let the scope chain handle the rest.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That way the compiler will throw `Cannot find name 'INITIALIZED' `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have TS recognize it as a valid window property by adding it to the `Window` interface:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        INITIALIZED: boolean | undefined;
    }
}
if (!window.INITIALIZED) {
  init();
  window.INITIALIZED = true;
}
runCode();
```

That said, assigning to properties of the global object is a *bit* of a code smell when not necessary. If at all possible, consider using an ordinary variable instead.

Comment: This works. :) If I want to do this, should I also place the `declare global` in the `index.d.ts` file?

Comment: Global changes like these can only be in a module (like with your other TS code), or in an ambient module declaration.

Comment: If you get the error "Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations." you can add export {} to the top of your type file type file as a "workaround"